# Am I on the Right Track in Evaluating ${{52 \choose x} \choose y}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I recently asked myself what would happen if one were to use the nCr function inside the nCr function. As an armchair mathematician, I don't study mathematics formally and am largely self-taught when it comes to Pre-Calculus and up, so please forgive (and feel free to help) with any misunderstandings that I demonstrate here.

To test out this question, I dove in the deep end and considered the number 52 as the base of the internal nCr function. This is to say, I wanted to do ${{52\choose x}\choose y}$. Naturally, I figured I would expand it out into its factorialised form:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{52!}{x!(52-x)!}\right)!}{y!\left(\frac{52!}{x!(52-x)!}-y\right)!}$$

Since this is a bit cumbersome, I decided to substitute the factorial forms for the $\Gamma$ function yielding the following:
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\Gamma(53)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(53-x)}+1\right)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma\left(\frac{\Gamma(53)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(53-x)}-y+1\right)}$$

Or,
$$\frac{f}{gh}$$

Such that $a=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{52}}{e^t}\right)dt, b=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{x}}{e^t}\right)dt, c=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{52-x}}{e^t}\right)dt, A=\frac{\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{52}}{e^t}\right)dt}{\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{x}}{e^t}\right)dt*\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{52-x}}{e^t}\right)dt}, f=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{A}}{e^t}\right)dt, g=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{y}}{e^t}\right)dt,$ and $h=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{A-y}}{e^t}\right)dt$.

(I'm sorry for formatting it like this; the LaTeX wouldn't render such a long equation.)

The first of my two questions comes with multiplying integrals. Since $b$ and $c$ are both results from the $\Gamma$ function, they will return a fixed (ie, constant) value. According to the rule $\int_a^b\int_c^d(f(x)*g(y))dxdy=\left(\int_a^b(g(y))dy\right)\left(\int_c^d(f(x))dx\right)$ allows for the combination in $A$ yielding $A=\frac{\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{52}}{e^t}\right)dt}{\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{52}}{e^{2t}}\right)dtdt}$ and the combination in $\frac{f}{gh}$ yielding $\frac{\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{A}}{e^t}\right)dt}{\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{t^{A}}{e^{2t}}\right)dtdt}$

At this point, I'm kind of stuck just from lack of experience. I don't know if I can combine those integrals like that or if I should change $t$ to a series of variables as placeholders for the double integrations or if I should just combine them. Conversely, I could look at the integrals as acting as constants because they will return 1 value (I'm pretty sure) allowing for me to use the rule $\int_a^b(k*f(x))dx=k\int_a^b(f(x))$.

Thus, my overall question: Am I on the right track to solving this? If it's not too presumptuous, please don't solve the problem for me, but rather just give me some pointers regarding whether the Constant Rule or the Combination Rule that I used is preferable.

In typing this out, I think the Constant Rule might be the way to go or, conversely, I could try using different variables other than $t$ in these $\Gamma$ functions so that I can integrate with respect to different variables.

I took Calculus in high school 5 years ago but hardly understood a thing after the turn of the semester. All of my understanding of Calculus at this level has been self-taught through reading and online videos when I came across notations or questions as I worked through problems on my own. Don't be afraid to explain it like I'm new (because I'm not a professional nor have I studied maths at a university level [beyond the requisite courses]), but I think I'm somewhat doing it right but I also have a large suspicion that I'm making some very glaring mistakes for people who do these kinds of operations regularly.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: One problem I see is that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^A}{e^{2t}} dt$ is a constant, so $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^A}{e^{2t}} dt dt = \int_0^{\infty} C dt = \infty$ diverges. I believe you tried to merge the two integrals $\left(\int_a^b f(t)dt\right)\left(\int_c^d g(t)dt\right)$. In that case, you should use different variables such as $\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x)g(y) dy dx$, or more clearly $\int_{x=a}^b \int_{y=c}^d f(x)g(y) dy dx$.

Comment: Yeah, that was something that I was thinking about when I typed out the question. I think that treating the $t$ in $b, c, g,$ and $h$ as the same variable threw off my work. I think I should use different variables so that the $\Gamma$ functions can be integrated distinctly for each instance. (Eg, use $t, u, v, w,$ &c and $dt, du, dv, dw$, &c

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use a different variable for every function. It is perfectly fine to say $F(x) = \int_a^b f(x) dx$ and $G(x) = \int_c^d g(x) dx$. It's just that when you perform the multiplying step, you cannot treat them as the same variable, they're on "different axes".

Comment: After fixing the problem above, I can [confirm](https://imgur.com/a/KcNR5Am) that your calculation and integrations are correct. I don't see how to simplify though ;) nice work

Comment: Thank you, @GarethMa ! I can't express how good it feels to kind of BS something and then find out that you were right especially when it's something as confusing as Calc can be.

I agree. I don't think this can be simplified unless a value were picked for either x or y, but at that point one could just plot is on a Cartesian plane with either x or y being along the horizontal axis and the result of the function being output on the vertical axis